# what's html5 manifest cache for?

Tags: html, caching, web

When server sets expire to far future on resources, shouldn't client recognize the resource is not expired and load it from its own cache? (no contact to server)

Why is this manifest cache required for offline browsing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html5 adds an "Application Cache" feature which is implemented by manifest files in the header of web pages. This application cache is different from the normal caching that browsers perform, and allows a developer to specify which portions of the website should be saved locally. The manifest can specify things like images, javascript files, xml documents and more. It gives the developer more control over how the website operates in offline mode.

The standard caching isn't designed specifically for supporting offline browsing. Its designed more for stuff like pressing the back button or rapidly viewing the same page, which is why the w3c added the new application cache.

Comment: Ok. one thing is still not clear. Even though `expire` is set far future, client contacts the server for the resource?

Comment: The html5 application cache never expires unless the manifest is changed. If we're talking about cache expire headers (which aren't related to the html5 application cache) then its up to the browser to decide whether to use the cached version. Most browsers will contact the server every once in a while even if the pages are cached locally.